# Forbidden request goolgle translate api

Tags: google-translate

I received error 403 (forbidden) doing a request to google translate. I have a free trial that ends in december 2023. api key is active. i use nordvpn.i don'use everyday.  in september it worked. var apiUrl = $"https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key={apiKey}";

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("source", "en"),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("target", language),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("q", text),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved . The credit card on the billing account for Google Cloud had expired. By fixing that, the issue was resolved.